# Composer does not install the dependencies

Tags: php, cmd, phpunit, composer-php

I have tried to install some dependencies that I need, for instance, PHPUnit and Slim, onto my project directory (not globally).

I have this in my composer.json,

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    }
}
```

This is my directory structure,

```
controller/
tests/
composer.json
```

When I run this line `composer update` on my Windows CMD, I get this message below on the CMD and it's just frozen there and doing nothing else. No PHPUnit is intall to my `vendor` directory at all.

[image]

any ideas what have I missed?

**EDIT:**

ping,

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

autoloading,

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Namespace\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The image you posted is not an error, just composer updating the dependencies and it could take time, also  phpunit now is over the 4.5 so better do "phpunit/phpunit": "4.5.*".
If you want to try an alternative just install phpunit with composer update phpunit/phpunit

Comment: I waited for more than 15 minutes but nothing is changed though...

Comment: try composer update phpunt/phpunit -v you will see the complete verbose messages, and maybe you could understand where is the block.

Comment: same thing. nothing happens...

Comment: what about composer update --prefer-dist -v

Comment: tried that. nothing as well. I have tried to install via Git Bash and the same thing happens. Might be something wrong with the Composer today? have you check on your end?

Comment: What do you mean install via Git bash, did you try to clone the phpunit repo via git? Because at this point I think maybe there is some connection problem. What about your previous vendors? How did you install them?

Comment: Let's try another way, find the composer cache dir and remove it, for finding is composer config cache-dir

Comment: thanks, but can't find composer folder in my program files folder.

Comment: i have uninstalled and then reinstalled composer back. but still the same...

Comment: the composer cache folder maybe is hidden, you have to show the hidden file and remove that folder.

Comment: I did that but still no improvement. might it be that my machine is effected by a virus that stops compuser from working properly?

Comment: could you ping www.packagist.com? inside cmd line. I think I deserve a beer now :-)

Comment: lol thanks for the help! please see my edit for ping-ing www.packagist.com. i don't understand what it says though...

Comment: thanks! the content in my `composer.json` is in my question above. please take a look.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, Do you have only phpunit in your composer?

Comment: Now I'm confused! I follow this video tutorial to install phpunit - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9YVcssCACI

Comment: it is not only phpunit that is not being installed by composer. many others too cannot be installed via composer, such as autoloading (see my edit 2) - it was working before.

Comment: I also have been following this page and nothing work http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-package-management-with-composer--net-25530

Comment: that's why I am asking if you could post, entirely your composer.json,
the autoload is wrong for example

Comment: sorry what do you mean `entirely your composer.json`? I have a `composer.json` in each of my project. What else can a `composer.json` be?

Comment: You have controller, test, and composer.json could you post all the lines in your composer, because you post 2 different sources

Comment: it's only `"phpunit/phpunit": "*"` I have in the first `composer.json`. nothing else. `"autoload"` is in another project, that's all and only that "autoload" in it, nothing else.

Comment: At this point I have a doubt, because I saw that you use EasyPHP web server on windows, do you know if openssl is enabled?
Open you php.ini and try to find this row, extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: yes, `openssl` is enabled. it is strange and I don't get it as I have followed all the step exactly. It might be some faulty with in machine itself.

Comment: The issue seems to be coming from composer server. if you google `Why updating of dependencies in composer is so slow`, you will see lots of report regarding this and there is no good solution yet (it seems!). Composer sucks!